# Check if a year is in PeriodIndex

Tags: pandas, period

I'm having a DataFrame which is indexed by PeriodIndex and need to check if the index contains a year.

Here is a snippet of what I have tried so far:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: period_ix = pd.period_range(start='2018-07-01', end='2019-04-30', freq='W')

In [3]: '2018' in period_ix
Out[3]: False

In [4]: '2018' in period_ix.year
Out[4]: False

In [5]: 2018 in period_ix.year
Out[5]: True

In [6]: 2018 in period_ix
Out[6]: False

In [7]: '2019' in period_ix
Out[7]: True

In [8]: '2019' in period_ix.year
Out[8]: False

In [9]: 2019 in period_ix.year
Out[9]: True

In [10]: 2019 in period_ix
Out[10]: False
```

I've resorted to use `int(year) in period_ix.year` since it produced the expected result for every year (be it string or int).

However, I am interested in using `'2018' in period_ix` since it seems more novel & consistent than what I'm doing. I guess that if one put in `'2018'`, it is interpreted as `'2018-01-01'` hence the False here.

Comment: Print the period_ix.year, you will see that is dtype int . so any string will not in it

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out, hence resorted to use `int(year) in period_ix.year`. However, I'm more interested in seeing if `year in period_ix` is possible, since to us it's cleaner.

Comment: I do not thinkg so , since the string or int can not be in the PeriodIndex, dtype is different

Comment: Please see the output: '2018' is not in the index (returned False) but '2019' is in.

Comment: `idx.isin(['2019']).any()` returns false, and Wen is right. Which is more correct according to you?

Comment: Seems the fancy indexing doesn't work identically with the PeriodIndex, as when it's set as the index of a DataFrame. For instance `pd.DataFrame(index=period_ix)['2018']` slices as you'd expect.

Comment: may be worth noting that you can use `'2018' in str(period.year)` if preserving the `'2018'` is really your main concern

Comment: Thing is... we inherited a messy code base with no type validation so what I've done so far is to cast every year back to integer and check the `period.year` LOL. I'm just interested in seeing why `'2019' in period` returns True and should it be used as the standard here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add a bit if information, [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) is performed differently with a `PeriodIndex`. You can see this most directly from:

```
period_ix.get_loc('2018')
#KeyError: Period('2018-01-01/2018-01-07', 'W-SUN')
```

The relevant lines are located [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/indexes/period.py#L679-L680) in the source code, so you can see the string `'2018'` is converted into

```
pd.period('2018', freq=period_ix.freq)
#Period('2018-01-01/2018-01-07', 'W-SUN')
```

which doesn't exist in your PeriodIndex.

---

You can get the same partial string slicing behavior using `PeriodIndex._get_string_slice`

```
period_ix[period_ix._get_string_slice('2018')]
#PeriodIndex(['2018-06-25/2018-07-01', '2018-07-02/2018-07-08',
#             '2018-07-09/2018-07-15', '2018-07-16/2018-07-22',
#             '2018-07-23/2018-07-29', '2018-07-30/2018-08-05',
#             '2018-08-06/2018-08-12', '2018-08-13/2018-08-19',
#             ....
#             '2018-12-24/2018-12-30', '2018-12-31/2019-01-06'],
#            dtype='period[W-SUN]', freq='W-SUN')
```

With just a year, I agree that your version of `int(year) in period_ix.year` is appropriate. Though if you want partial with year and month, you may need something like:

```
not period_ix[period_ix._get_string_slice('2018-08')].empty
True
```

Or

```
def contains_partl(date, pidx):
    sl = pidx._get_string_slice(date)  #slice
    return sl.start != sl.stop

contains_partl('2018', period_ix)
#True

contains_partl('2018-05', period_ix)
#False
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have had the same suspicion (stated in my question) that `'2018'` is converted to `'2018-01-01'`. I'm happy to accept this as an answer if you would put in using `int(year) in period_ix.year` as maybe the suitable way to do this.